# Disable a Prefab when Clicked

Tags: unity, c#

I want to disable the Question Prefab so that when it is clicked the Prefab behind it will be shown:

I am using Unity 5.3.5 and C#.

Comment: Do you have a correct ollider on the object that also has your script?

Comment: I have a Box Collider 2D on the GameObject

Comment: I think this code disables all the objects that contains this script. Can you please elaborate what you actually want??

Comment: I want that when i press on one of the question prefabs the image that there is behind it will be shown. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created a new gameObject and added this script:

Why did you created a new gameObject when you wanted to disable the prefab clones?.

There's nothing wrong with the *given* code. You should put the script on your **Prefab**.

If it still doesn't work. You can use [EventSystems](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html) to get the Game Object that is currently selected and deactivate it.

[Check this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVZiv7DLU6E&feature=youtu.be) for how to use Event Systems.

Comment: Ok thanks i managed to do it... Now how can i match a pair of cards. I have a prefabs folder with 18 images which are duplicated in the same folder, so the total cards is 36.. How can i make unity identify that 2 cards are the same. Thanks